How Draw FirePropagationModel On Cesium.js
FirePropagationModel
I have to draw this complex shape in cesium.js passing the parameters width depth in meters and orientation from 0 to 360 for the wind direction what should I use to draw this propagation model.
Instructions on how to draw complex shape in cesium.js
